# How to disable form submit if the username is not available

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have checked the user name availability. The problem is, even if the username is not available, the form is posting.

**Edited Code:**

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#emailch").change(function() { 

    var usr = $("#emailch").val();
    if(usr.length >= 3)
    {
        $("#status").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "includes/check.php",  
            data: "username="+ usr,  
            success: function(msg){   
                $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 
                    if(msg == 'OK')
                    { 
                        $("#username").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                        $("#username").addClass("object_ok");
                        $(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="images/tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                        $("#username").addClass("object_error");
                        $(this).html(msg);


                    }

                });

            }
        }); 
    }

    else
    {
        $("#status").html('<font color="red">The username should have at least <strong>3</strong> characters.</font>');
        $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
        $("#username").addClass("object_error");
    }

});

});
</SCRIPT>
```

What I want is that, **the form should not be posted if the user name is not available**. I have tried by using `return false;` in IF CONDITION but it fails. Please suggest any alternate method. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From where are you calling this code? Show us the context of it. `return false;` will work, you just have to put it in the right place.

Comment: Where are calling this function? Inside the onsubmit handler?

Comment: @Jan Hancic , Salman , Code is Edited. Please Check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on submit return false no matter what, if the field is good do your ajax send of the form, if its bad, error out or whatever you need

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" id="formId" method="post">
<input type="text" id="emailch" name="emailch" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#formId").submit( function() { 

        if( $("#emailch").val().length >= 3){
            alert( 'the form is going to post via ajax here' );
        }else{
            alert( 'user name invalid error out or whatever you need to do.' );
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using return false to stop a form from being submitted doesn't really work that well in jQuery. Use event.preventDefault() instead, try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#formid').submit(function(event) {
        if ($("#emailch").val().length < 3) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `return false;` works just fine, what are the problems you are facing with it?

Comment: Oh, you seem to be right. I clearly remember testing it a while ago though, and I don't think it worked then (but event.preventDefault() did). Must have borked something up.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag (variable) in your `success` function to `false` (for instance) if the username is not available. Then check that flag in your form's `onsubmit` handler, and if the flag equals false, return false from that event handler, and your form will not submit.