# javascript: if username exists, then not submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my previous thread about using ajax to check availability of username when registering 
[jQuery: check username availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675730/jquery-check-username-availability)
Now when I test the system, the ajax works fine, but even I use the existing username, when I click "submit" button, the form will be submitted. I assume I need an additional javascript to stop this from happening, how can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to continue to receive help, you might want to accept an answer on a previous question before asking more questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable form submit if the username is not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864739/how-to-disable-form-submit-if-the-username-is-not-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you take a measure to disable your submit button when you determine whether the username is a duplicate.

To fit into your existing code:

```
if(data=="no"){
   $(this).html("This username already exists");
   $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
}
else{
   $(this).html("Username is available!");
   $('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

If you wanted to refactor it a bit:

```
$('input[name=submit]').attr('disabled', (data=="no"));
$(this).html((data=="no")?"This username already exists":"Username is available!");
```

Comment: Disabling the submit button is one way to achieve your goal, but keep in mind that if you add another submitting widget (e.g. a submit button or image or a text field) then the form could still get submitted even though it shouldn't be!  Consider trapping the form submit action, per my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to prevent the form from being submitted; the [jQuery documentation for "submit()"](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) is helpful here.  Assuming you've got a method that checks if the username exists (or a flag that can be set based on the result of your AJAX call):

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="" />
...
<script>
  $("form").submit(function() {
    // Return false if the form should NOT be submitted.
    return !usernameExists(selectedUsername);
  });
</script>
```

Or to fit it into your code example from the other question:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  return data!='no';
});
if(data=="no"){
  $(this).html("This username already exists");
  //...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have taken campbell's solution.